# dropdown showing improper values

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a web form in which there are some controls along with dropdown list as below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrange"  CssClass="dropdownstate" style="position:absolute;top:224px; left:200px;" runat="server" >
         <asp:ListItem >Select Range</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="A" >A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="B" >B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="C" >C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="D" >D</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

and theres a gridview in which data is shown on btninsert click.
and I have a link button EDIT. on clicking edit the corresponding values are displayed in their respective controls.
Now, coming to the point,insert works fine, but when i click on Edit link every thing is fine except the value in dropdown list.

it should be like as shown in screenshot below:

[image]

but what I get is shown below:

[image]

how can I overcome this???

Comment: Before clicking Edit was A selected in DropDown?

Comment: @Anuj- No,only After clicking edit A is shown in dropdownlist.

Comment: what you expect to be selected in dropdown when you click edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `ddlrange.SelectedValue` instead of `ddlrange.SelectedItem.Text`, and issue is solved.

Thanks everyone for your efforts, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving value to the Select Range list item and then chcek, may be that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<asp:ListItem Value=null>Select Range</asp:ListItem>` line.

**Try Below:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrange"  CssClass="dropdownstate" style="position:absolute;top:224px; left:200px;" runat="server" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="Select Range">Select Range</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="A" >A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="B" >B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="C" >C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="D" >D</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful for you

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrange"  CssClass="dropdownstate" style="position:absolute;top:224px; left:200px;" runat="server" >
     <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="" >Select Range</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="A" >A</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="B" >B</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="C" >C</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="D" >D</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

In edit click event add a "Select Range" value into the drop down.

```
 ddlRange.Items.Insert (0,"Select Range");
```